# Replace values with awk for loop in specific rows

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I would like to replace the values 3 and 4 for 0 and 1, respectively, in all fields in the first, third, fiveth row and so on until the end of the following data set:

```
 2 4 3 0
 2 4 3 0
 3 0 4 4
 3 0 4 4
 4 2 4 3
 4 2 4 3
 2 3 4 2
 2 3 4 2
```

So, the desired result is:

```
 2 1 0 0
 2 4 3 0
 0 0 1 1
 3 0 4 4
 1 2 1 0
 4 2 4 3
 2 0 1 2
 2 3 4 2
```

I'm using the following code to do that:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NR; i=(i+2)) 
    if($i == 3) {$i = 0}
    if($i == 4) {$i = 1} 
}
END {print $0}' b.temp
```

However, the output for this code is only the values in the last row of b.temp file (2 3 4 2).

How can I do that? The code needs to that for any numer of rows and fields. The solution can be in awk, sed or other alternative in shell script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 'y/34/01/;n' file
```

Which means:

- Replace 3 and 4 by 0 and 1 in this line and print it;
- Get next line and print it;
- Get next line and repeat cycle.

This would however fail if the data contained, for example, 14, transforming it to 11. To work around that, opt for

```
sed 's/\<4\>/1/g;s/\<3\>/0/g;n' file
```

[Those `\<` and `\>` matches the beginning and end of a word.](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I want do to a similar thing as before but start in the second row, like replace the values 3 and 4 by 1 and 0 (inverse order of the main question) in the second, fourth, sixth row and so on. Is it possible to do that usin a similar aproach?

Comment: @andrec Yes, you just need to put `n` before the `y` and invert the replacement order inside `y` command. I.e., `sed 'n;y/34/10/' file`.

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your approach is that you have only one `print` statement, in the `END` block. The value of `$0` in that block is the content of the last line of your file. So, your `awk` code will only print the last line of the file.

Also, note that `awk` applies the operations to *every line* unless you have a condition before the `{ ... }` blocks (such as `END` which applies only to end-of-file). So, your code would try to check the 1st, 3rd etc *field* of *every line* and if it is `3` or `4` replace that with `0` or `1` respectively ... but never print the result.

In order apply a rule to every odd line, you can check if `NR%2` is one (or simply non-zero):

```
awk 'NR%2{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==3 || $i==4) $i-=3}1' b.temp
```

The `1`, when occuring outside of a rule, is an `awk` shorthand notation for "print the line resulting from all transformations performed".

Answer (score 0):

More OPtimised command would be there below is my try

Command

```
awk 'NR==1||NR==3||NR==5||NR==7{gsub("3","0",$0)}1' file | awk 'NR==1||NR==3||NR==5||NR==7{gsub("4","1",$0)}1'
```

output

```
 2 1 0 0
 2 4 3 0
 0 0 1 1
 3 0 4 4
 1 2 1 0
 4 2 4 3
 2 0 1 2
 2 3 4 2
```

Comment: Besides needlessly calling awk twice (just do two gsubs), this would replace "44" with "11" (and 333 with 000).